# Easy way for adding users to TFS Team Projects

Tags: tfs

To add users to TFS Team Projects, we need to add them in multiple places accessing Team Explorer, Share Point Portal and Reporting Site. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TFS Administration tool](http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/): It allows the users to set the permissions for Team Foundation, Share Point and Reporting Services Roles from one window.

Answer (score 1):

We set up some Active Directory groups which mirror the groups set up my TFS so for "TeamProject Contributors" we'd have a group called "domain\TFS TeamProject Contributors" the AD groups are then added to the groups in the team project and given the appropriate permissions in sharepoint and reporting services.

It's a little extra effort to set up when creating a new team project, but once it's done it makes adding new users much easier. Just add them to the AD group and they automatically have the correct permissions for all of the bits of TFS.